# How to get hostname call my API

Tags: php, codeigniter

Eg: `website abc.com` access my REST API  by link `xyz.com/rest/api/order/new`
. In my function, how can I get hostname `abc.com`?

I want to check the token is matched with the hostname that is saved in the database.

Comment: See [`$_SERVER`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Comment: @AlexHowansky i have tried it but the result always return "xyz.com" :(

Comment: Oops sorry, my mistake, misunderstood your question.

Comment: Try with this `$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` to get the abc.com and then make `$ip = gethostbyname($referer); echo $ip;`

Comment: You can not reliably get the hostname of the server that's hitting your API. You *can* get its IP (from `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`) though, and then perhaps to a DNS lookup on it.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Do you know how to DNS lookup on it? @@ I have tried many ways but no result

Comment: @elddenmedio it still show the hostname of API server

Comment: what is the info that `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` and `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` gives you

Comment: @elddenmedio sorrry for reply you late, yesterday i was so tired with this issuse,  $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] return Undefined index: HTTP_REFERER. $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] return my IP address

Answer (score 0):

use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']` for get host name.

```
print_r($_SERVER);
```

then you will see all output

or use

```
$hostname = gethostname();
```

or use

```
 $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
```

or if you want something else then

```
print_r($_SERVER);
```

then check data and use your require data

for more information

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: OP is looking for the remote host -- gethostname() and HTTP_HOST give you the local host.

Comment: @ShafiqulIslam i have tried "gethostbyaddr($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"])" but it return their server host, not "abc.com"

Answer (score 0):

For codeigniter, you can use:

```
$this->input->server('HTTP_HOST');
```

In argument, you can use all options of $_SERVER veriable.

Comment: This gives you the local host, OP is looking for the remote host.